# Groovy as operator producing strange error

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors, casting

I am encountering a very strange error that I am completely lost on produced by the following code snippet:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = [:] as Map<String, Map<String, String>>
println(map)
```

I was using the as operator like this to fix warnings on unknown map retrievals (here replaced with `[:]` for simplicity) before without any problems. But this case suddenly produces this error in IntelliJ:

```
startup failed:
main.groovy: 4: expecting EOF, found 'println' @ line 4, column 1.
   println(map)
   ^

1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Or this one in a Groovy Web Shell (https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/):

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 2: expecting EOF, found 'println' @ line 2, column 1.
   println(map)
   ^

1 error
```

I can work around the problem by casting with `(Map<String, Map<String, String>>)` but I would like to understand what is causing this problem.

Comment: Unless running in typechecked mode, groovy doesn't really "do" generics

Comment: but it still shouldn't produce an error like this from my understanding. I assume it has to do with the nested structure but I only get the problem with the as operator.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the parser not being able to scan the code. You shouldn't need the `as`...  `String a = 'a' as String` is the same as `String a = 'a'`

Comment: I've checked the code you provided, for me it works perfect, the empty map is printed. Maybe you have something else in your `main.groovy`? Here is my version of Groovy: `Groovy Version: 4.0.3 JVM: 15.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`

Comment: That's surprising as I also used an online shell to validate the error with no other code inside (linked in my post). This is my local version: ```Groovy Version: 4.0.0 JVM: 17.0.5 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10
```